# cannot reach to http://localhost:7180 using Cloudera Quickstart VM

Tags: docker, cloudera

I am Installing Cloudera Quickstart VM through Docker Hub (on Mac) 
 sudo /home/cloudera/cloudera-manager --force
[root@quickstart /]#  sudo /home/cloudera/cloudera-manager --express --force
[QuickStart] Shutting down CDH services via init scripts...
kafka-server: unrecognized service
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
[QuickStart] Disabling CDH services on boot...
error reading information on service kafka-server: No such file or directory
[QuickStart] Starting Cloudera Manager server...
[QuickStart] Waiting for Cloudera Manager API...
[QuickStart] Starting Cloudera Manager agent...
[QuickStart] Configuring deployment...
Submitted jobs: 14
[QuickStart] Deploying client configuration...
[QuickStart] Starting Cloudera Management Service...
Submitted jobs: 24
[QuickStart] Enabling Cloudera Manager daemons on boot...

---

Success! You can now log into Cloudera Manager from the QuickStart VM's browser:

```
http://quickstart.cloudera:7180
```

The issue is, I don't see a web page while I try 
http://localhost:7180/

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So you have a Virtual Machine with docker running Cloudera or ? Ensure your VM is running Bridged and not NAT.

Comment: I am Installing Cloudera Quickstart VM through Docker Hub (on Mac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with false Success message from above command.

Actually not all the services was getting started because of lack of memory.

I increase RAM from Docker--> Preference --> 16 GB, restart Docker and issue again below command
sudo /home/cloudera/cloudera-manager
I can see page while hitting http://localhost:7180/cmf/login

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by mapping an output port for the "7180" port for the docker container.

You can do it in various ways, the easiest one is to configure it from the begging.

You can make the container by the following command:

```
$ docker run -m 8G --memory-reservation 4G --memory-swap 8G --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -t -i -v $(pwd):/hilati --publish-all=true -p8888 -p8088 -p7180 cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

> PS: change whatever you want based on your needs.